# Error : Type mismatch: inferred type is FirstFragment but Context was expected

Tags: kotlin

I'm tring to build an app can dial ussd code on my mobile so,
i have 2 errors in my code on kotlin, how can i solve my problem?

First Error: **(Type mismatch: inferred type is FirstFragment but Context was expected)**
and
Second Error: **(Type mismatch: inferred type is FirstFragment but Activity was expected)**

Here is my complete code

```
package gaur.himanshu.august.tablayout.fragments

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import gaur.himanshu.august.tablayout.MainActivity
import gaur.himanshu.august.tablayout.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_first.*

class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

val REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
}



override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    button.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "You Clicked the Button",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()


        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                REQUEST_PHONE_CALL
            )
        }
        else {
            startCall()
        }

    } // END button


} // override fun onViewCreated



override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PHONE_CALL) {
        startCall()
    }
    //super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}



private fun startCall() {

    if(zaad_Merchant_SLSH.text.isNotEmpty() && merchant.text.isNotEmpty()) {
        var zaadFieldINT = zaad_Merchant_SLSH.text.toString().toInt()
        var phoneNumber = merchant.text.toString().toInt()


        if(zaadFieldINT < 500) {

            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "The Value is Less than 500",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()

        }

        else {
            val merchantNum = "*223*$phoneNumber*$zaadFieldINT%23"
            val callIntent  = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            callIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + merchantNum)
            startActivity(callIntent)
        }
    }


    if(zaad_Merchant_SLSH.text.isEmpty() && merchant.text.isEmpty()) {
        
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Labada Khaanadood way madhan yihiin",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        
    }

    else if(merchant.text.isEmpty()) {
        //editText.text = "Labada Khanadood way madhan yihiin"
        
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Khaanada Telephone Num way madhantahay",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        
    }

    else if(zaad_Merchant_SLSH.text.isEmpty()) {
        //editText.text = "Labada Khanadood way madhan yihiin"
        
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Khaanada Lacagta way madhantahay",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()

        
    }

} // END startcall()
```

}

Comment: the error in section => (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` must be a `Context`. If you were writing this code inside an `Activity` (which is a subclass of `Context`), then passing `this` would work just fine. But since you're in a `Fragment` (which is **not** a subclass of `Context`), you can't pass `this`.

Try passing `view.context` instead. Or use `requireActivity()` in any spot where an `Activity` (and not just a `Context`) is needed.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer if it solved your problem, as a signal to future users that this answer was helpful. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Mr ben, my account say: You can't vote for your own post, how can i vote?